# Power Automate Date condition problems

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, power-automate, powerapp

I have been working in a flow that alert a user once a certain certification expires, to achieve this I'm using a SharePoint list that contains the dates data.

The idea was to create a counter column that autoupdates daily and a calculated column that calculates the expiration date of every cert and then compare both of them and determine the course of action if the condition is met.

The problem is that when I compare both columns using an If statement they don't return anything and the workflow just run without an error. Any idead of what might be happening? thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ticks function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks) when comparing dates. Here is one blog post that describes how to use the ticks function: [How to compare dates in Power Automate](https://debajmecrm.com/how-to-compare-dates-in-power-automate/). A search for "power automate date comparison" will get you additional resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether it returns true or false in your if statement. If it does not return the correct value, then you need to check whether the type of the value in if statement is correct. For example, you counter column value could be int or float, however when you use if the value is equal to "0", it will return false as "0" is a string type, you need to change "0" into 0.